# Is there any way to choos to which PoP you want to connect in a CDN?

Tags: networking, dns, cdn, spoofing

I would like to know if there is any way I can dinamicaly choose to which Point Of Presence connect my PC when I'm accessing for instance [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (who has 16 Data Centers) or facebook. I think that maybe it's possible by using a VPN and changing the location so that the DNS would think I'm for exmaple in the USA so I have to connect to google USA data center. Is there any way I can code something like this so I can dinamically change my apparent location to the DNS ?

Comment: Connecting directly to a Google or Facebook server in the US will not change your DNS provider or where your request is coming from.

Answer (score -1):

you should to direct PoP hostname to IP in custom location using hosts on your local PC

For example:
`x.x.x.x cdn.yoursite.com`
where `x.x.x.x` is PoP IP in custom location

Comment: Your answer is not very clear. Perhaps what you are telling the user to do, is perform a manual DNS query on the domain they are intending to access, then do a geo graphical search on each IP address, then when they find the address that is closest to them, they can edit their hosts file to hard code the IP addy to the specific server they want to access which currently is DNS resolved by a pool response. Though I'm still not sure if a hosts file can resolve an entire domain such as google.com to a single IP address.